# Iterating and adding links in selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium, web, automation, webdriver

Hello I got an issue to make it work.
I was able to make this working for the single automation, but now I want to do the for loop just to add multiple links into the form.
Basically, I would like to take from .csv file with links. After adding first link, second row is copied and used search.send_keys("element").
Many thanks for suggestions

First code works as a single input.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=/users/sb/Documents/UserData")
options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("database for links")

time.sleep(5)

search = driver.find_element("id", "link box")
search.send_keys("link to be added")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

#waiting for adding the link
time.sleep(20)

#End 
search = driver.find_element("id", "modalclose").click()
```

Iteration implantation, which is not working

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
import xlrd

data_from_excel('/users/user/Downloads/links.csv.xls')
data_list = []
data = xlrd.open_workbook('/users/user/Downloads/links.csv.xls')
sheet = data.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet.cell_value(0, 0)
for i in range(sheet.nrows):
data_list.append(sheet.cell_value(i, 0))
return data_list
for element in data_list:
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=/users/sb/Documents/UserData")
options.page_load_strategy = 'normal'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("link to the form")
time.sleep(5)
search = driver.find_element("id", "link box")
search.send_keys("element")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

#waiting for adding the link
time.sleep(10)

#end 
search = driver.find_element("id", "modalclose").click()
```

Comment: First resolve the indentation issue and when you say not working, what error are you getting. Post the error stack as well.